# как получить высоту картинки и записать ее в блок

Tags: css

как получить высоту картинки и записать ее в блок ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так.

```js
let img = document.getElementById("picture");
img.onload = function() {
    let imgHeight = img.height;
    document.getElementById("block").style.height = imgHeight + "px";
};
```

```css
#block{
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<img id="picture" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net
C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="img">
<div id="block"></div>
```

Хотя, совершенно непонятно зачем это вам. Сейчас все дизайны ретиновые, и размеры тянуться.